# Loop through range and append values based on count

Tags: excel

Search the web and SO, but couldn't find an answer that helped me.  Hoping a direct question can lead to community enlightenment.

I want to create code that looks through a range (column headers), detects duplicates, and then appends each duplicate with the count.

For example, my column headers look like this:

- Vendor
- Tracking Number
- Display In
- Type
- Call Report Flag
- Type
- Due
- Created By
- Created
- Created By
- Created

After running the code, I would like them to look like this:

- Vendor
- Tracking Number
- Display In
- Type1
- Call Report Flag
- Type2
- Due
- Created By1
- Created1
- Created By2
- Created2

Non-duplicates were left alone, duplicates have been appended by the current count.

I've attempted some code and it counts the # of duplicates using 'for each cell in my range' but once it appends the count, it then no-longer sees it as a duplicate, so when it moves to the next cell it won't append.

Here's my code (although I think I may need to start with a different strategy):

Sub TestSub()

```
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Headers As Range

Set Headers = Worksheets("TEST SHEET").UsedRange.Rows("1:1")
Counter = 1

For Each Cell In Headers.Cells.Value
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Headers, Cell.Value) > 1 Then
        Cell.Value = Cell.Value & Counter
    End If
    Counter = Counter + 1
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the basics of this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(1:1,A1)>1,A1&COUNTIF($A$1:A$1,A1),A1)
```

To do what you want:

```
Sub TestSub()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Headers As Range
Dim Headers2 As Range
With Worksheets("TEST SHEET")
    Set Headers = .UsedRange.Rows("1:1")
    Headers.Copy .Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count)
    Set Headers2 = .UsedRange.Rows(.Rows.Count & ":" & .Rows.Count)

    For Each Cell In Headers.Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Headers2, Cell.Value) > 1 Then
            Cell.Value = Cell.Value & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A" & .Rows.Count, .Cells(.Rows.Count, Cell.Column)), Cell.Value)
        End If
    Next Cell
    Headers2.ClearContents

End With
End Sub
```

We need to copy the headers to another location to use as in the COUNTIF().  Otherwise once the first gets changed none of the other will be equal and the countif fails to find more than one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott.  This might work.  Let me ask an additional question.

Is there a way to, instead of copying the headers to another location, store the original headers in an array?

Comment: There is but then COUNTIF will not work, and we will need to do a lot more looping and logic to make it work.  I assumed that there is no data on the last line in the sheet, depending on version that is either around 65,000 or 1,000,000.

Comment: Understood - I wondered if values in an array would change or remain static; you answered that.  Your code above has a reference to "Sheet3" - was this an error?  (assuming this is meant to be "TEST SHEET")

Comment: @JTaylor see the edit.  you may need to refresh the page.

Comment: @JTaylor remember to mark as answered if this works for you.